# Sometime background in fragment is invisible and visible just border

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, view, android-drawable

I have problem with fragment background. Sometimes the background is invisible and visible is only short border. The problem is only samsung devices (S3, S5 mini tested) Example:

GOOD:
[image]
BAD:
[image]

In fragment is viewPager with 3 fragments
I use drawable background like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/radius"
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/radius"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/black_opacity_transparent"/>
    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: My Alternatif solution is make a Background in Photoshop and set the Capacity or Fill to lower so it will transparent

Comment: This is bad solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:bottom="-20dp">
                <shape
                    android:shape="rectangle">
                    <corners
                        android:radius="6dp"/>
                    <solid android:color="@color/black_opacity"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="10dp"
                        android:left="10dp"
                        android:right="10dp"
                        android:top="10dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```